# Apache2 AWS server returning 301

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I created a Ubuntu 14.04 instance on AWS, installed apache2 (via apt-get) and wordpress and everything was working fine until I tried to attach an elastic ip address to it.  At that point I lost connection through http.  I can still connect via ssh and can ping the server, but upon further inspection, discovered the server is returning a 301 and redirecting to the old public dns name.  Where is this redirect coming from?  I have no .htaccess files.